# Sending XML header with SimpleSamlPhp

Tags: php, xml, saml, xml-declaration

I'm using [SimpleSamlPhp](http://simplesamlphp.org/) for [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) Service Provider.

SimpleSamlPhp is sending sending auth request without xml headers, but IdP says they require an xml header. How can I add utf-8 header to request? (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)

This is how I send

`<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="gfpdfaailecofabshsehljipgpofofghjjahggi" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2011-08-23T06:26:06Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:
etc.....`

This is how IdP asks for

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="gfpdfaailecofabshsehljipgpofofghjjahggi" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2011-08-23T06:26:06Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:
etc.....`

PS:  Tested my SP on Feide OpenIdp and works fine.

Comment: Can you show the code where you fire the request? And have you contacted the mailinglist?

Comment: I'm using built-in test page of SimpleSamlPhp.

Comment: I have problems to locate that test. Can you provide the file-name of it or the URL how you access it?

Comment: simpleSAMLphp installation page -> authentication tab -> Test configured authentication sources -> default-sp . Url is something like /simplesaml/module.php/saml/disco.php?entityID=...etc